# Why does the EPEL Repo fail on a Centos 7 VM on VMWare Workstation 11?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, centos, vmware-workstation, repository

I created a Centos 7 VM on VMware Workstation 11 on a windows 7 host.  I am trying to reach the EPEL repo using

```
 sudo yum update -y
```

and I get the following error:

```
 [root@localhost vagrant]# sudo yum update -y
 Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks


   One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
   and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
  safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

  1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

  2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
    upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
    distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
    packages for the previous distribution release still work).

  3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
    just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
    --enablerepo for temporary usage:

        yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

  4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
    Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
    so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
    slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
    compromise:

        yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

 Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again
```

I have tried the following command and was able to reach the other repos:

```
 sudo yum --disablerepo epel check-update
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: I used the following command and it worked... How do I get is to work with https?   sudo sed -i 's/https/http/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo

Comment: This seems to be already answered at http://serverfault.com/questions/637549/epel-repo-for-centos-6-causing-error